# How to add favicon to robots.txt

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt

How can I disallow this URL: `http://www.example.com/assets/ico/favicon.png`?

Would these lines in my *robots.txt* work?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blah/assets*
Disallow: /blah/assets/ico/
```

Comment: Why do you have `/blah` in your robots.txt while the URL starts with `/assets` (and doesn’t contain "blah")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of those would work, but they would also block anything else in those directories.  If you only want to block that specific URL, you could do:

```
Disallow: */blah/assets/ico/favicon.png
```

Do you have a Google Webmasters Account setup?  If so they have a new robots.txt test page where you can see if a URL is blocked or not based on your robots file.

EDIT:  My original answer had the below. This would block all URLs that end with favicon.png since it has the $ at the end, but it's pointless in this case since only one favicon.png file can be in that directory.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961

```
Disallow: */blah/assets/ico/favicon.png$
```

Comment: Since when has `$` been allowed in robots.txt? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961.  To block any URLs that end in a specific way, use $.  I guess it's technically not needed in this case since you can't have more than one favicon.png file in that directory.  But it's certainly allowed in robots.txt.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I edited my original answer to say the `$` is not needed in this case

Comment: Why do you have the `*` at the beginning of the `Disallow` path? For parsers following the original robots.txt specification, your `Disallow` line won’t block the favicon.

Comment: @user well technically you could have `favicon.png` and `favicon.pngx` if such a file extension existed, so you would need the `$` in that case. As noted in my answer below, I would steer clear of using non-standard extensions unless there is no other way to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't block your favicon image unless you have a very good reason.

What exactly is the 'blah' supposed to represent in your example? If the URL is as you state in the question, you should just use:

```
Disallow: /assets/ico/favicon.png
```

That will prevent crawling of the specific image. To block the whole ico directory, use:

```
Disallow: /assets/ico/
```

In robots.txt, any path listed matches URLs starting only from the beginning, so the above matches anything beginning with `/assets/ico/`.

There is no such thing as a `*` wildcard for Disallow in the robots.txt standard. It is a non-standard extension that [according to Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) is only supported by Google.

Comment: The major search engines (at least Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Ask) support `*` as a wildcard in disallow in some way.  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: OK, but others such as Duck Duck Go don't appear to (they are at least as popular as Ask). Regardless, the `*` wildcard isn't necessary in this situation anyway.

Comment: Depends if this would apply to multiple directories of the same structure, but yes you are probably right.  And Duck Duck Go is nowhere near as popular as Ask.

Comment: @user ok maybe you're right about DDG. I'm constantly hearing about it, but never anything about Ask, so it certainly *seems* more popular.